# Python - print function output

Tags: python

```
def cent_to_fahr(cent):
    print (cent / 5.0 * 9 + 32)

print (cent_to_fahr(20))
```

The output is this :

```
68.0
None
```

Why this output has `None`?

I didn't get this result when I use just `cent_to_fahr(20)`. Can I ask why it happens ?

Comment: `cent_to_fahr` prints the result and the caller prints the return value of this function which is `None`.

Comment: I didn't get this result when i use just cent_to_fahr(20).Can i ask why it happens ?

Comment: In that case you have only the `print` in the function which prints the calculated value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it into context, let's try understand what causes each line of output you received:

- `68.0` is printed thanks to the **contents** of your function.
  This could be seen as the "end" of that computation's "life", that value/result is no longer available for further computations.
- `None` is what the function **returns**, and in this case is also quite useless.

Now that we understand that better, I would recommend adjusting the function to *return* the value computed.

```
def cent_to_fahr(cent):
    return (cent / 5.0 * 9 + 32)
```

That way when the function is called (in context of further functions) it will return a value that that can be further processed (in this case with `print()`):

```
>>>print(cent_to_fahr(20))
```

Which will print `68.0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def cent_to_fahr(cent):
    return (cent / 5.0 * 9 + 32)

print (cent_to_fahr(20))
```

a function needs to `return` a value to have an output other then `None`

Comment: I didn't get this result when i use just cent_to_fahr(20).Can i ask why it happens ?

Comment: @Gingerbread think of return like just a number. If you call Cent_to_fahr(20) you get 68.0 if you say a = Cent_to_fahr(20). a is now 68.0. You need to print the number to see it. so print(Cent_to_fahr(20)) will print it but just doing Cent_to_fahr(20) will do nothing.