# Python Beginner: Why is this my output? function generate at 0x0000021EE6848700

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate random numbers using user input. This is for a homework question and is structured as the professor instructed. I'm returning x amount of this instead of numbers.  function generate at 0x0000021EE6848700

I feel like this is a stupid question and I'm missing something obvious. When I try to define main with generate I get an error that I'm missing a positional argument. I have tried using print and return, and neither under generate. Am I not defining something correctly?

```
import random
def generate():
    print(random.randint(-100, 100))
def main():
    howMany=int(input('How many random numbers do you want: '))
    for count in range(howMany):
        print(generate)

main()
```

Comment: You need to call it with `generate()`

Comment: You are printing a function (`generate`), not the execution of it. For example `generate()`

Comment: In order for above suggestion to work, you also need to return, not print in `generate`. Otherwise you will also get an additional `None` printed.

Comment: Also the function `generate` will print inside it and return nothing so you have no need to print it again... Replace `print(generate)` with `generate()`

Comment: @matszwecja it will work if you keep the print within generate, but then you would need to call the function, not print it.

Comment: @warped downvotes are because this question could be easily avoided by a bit of research or going through a decent Python tutorial.

Comment: Indeed this is covered throughout multiple questions with different scopes, just googling "how to print output of a function python" shows this as first answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224795/python-print-function-output with a very similar issue.

Comment: I did Google for about 45 minutes. I was apparently not searching the correct question and was looking for the reason for the output, which did not return anything. I appreciate peoples help. I will Google better in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling the `generate` method - you're literally printing *the method itself*. I think that you meant `print(generate())`.

That being said, `print(generate())` doesn't make sense either because `generate()` doesn't return anything - it already prints. If you want to print the result of `generate` in `main`, you should return the result instead of printing. If you do that, though, the `generate` function wouldn't make much sense in the first place because all it would do is return the result of `random.randint(-100, 100)`. In that case, you should just call that method "directly."

So, the corrected versions could be any one of the following:

```
def generate():
    print(random.randint(-100, 100))
def main():
    howMany=int(input('How many random numbers do you want: '))
    for count in range(howMany):
        # Let the generate() function print
        generate()
```

or

```
def generate():
    return random.randint(-100, 100)
def main():
    howMany=int(input('How many random numbers do you want: '))
    for count in range(howMany):
        print(generate())
```

However, in this second version, the `generate` function is kind of pointless; it would be better to just do:

```
def main():
    howMany=int(input('How many random numbers do you want: '))
    for count in range(howMany):
        print(random.randint(-100, 100))
```

Comment: Thank you. This gave me a better understanding of needing to call the defined function, whereas how I originally wrote it was just printing generate. Thank you for the help.